# Failing reprojecting from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3857

Tags: coordinate-system, csv, ogr2ogr

I am trying to reproject a CSV file from EPSG:4326 (WGS84 lat/long points) to EPSG:3857 (Web Mercator in meters).

Here is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 Output.csv Input.csv
```

But it fails:

Input:

```
48.63674, -2.34785
48.63669, -2.34791
48.63658, -2.34801
```

Output:

```
field_1,field_2
"48.63674"," -2.34785"
"48.63669"," -2.34791"
"48.63658"," -2.34801"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't told ogr what the coordinate columns are

Comment: @IanTurton even just doing that isn't a complete solution....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problems are that you need to specify the input field names and also that you need to tell the driver to keep the geometry using the `-lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY` option, otherwise it throws the geometry away (https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html).

Using `field_1` etc seems to be ok for column numbers when there's no header for the `X/Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES` "open" options:

```
  ogr2ogr -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY \
    -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=field_1 \
    -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=field_2  \
    -t_srs epsg:3857  -s_srs epsg:4326 outx.csv Input.csv
```

Results in this output:

```
X,Y,field_1,field_2
5414217.13064484,-261434.642363928,48.63674,-2.34785
5414211.5646703,-261441.327145185,48.63669,-2.34791
5414199.31952631,-261452.46844792,48.63658,-2.34801
```

There's probably some way of dropping the fields in the output if you really don't need them but it took me a zillion goes to get this far :)

Comment: Works great! thanks for this detailed answer!